# Cookie not registered at http (in php)

Tags: php, http, cookies, cpanel, setcookie

The cookie is stored in https but not registered in http

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store');
var_dump($_COOKIE);
function ishttp(){
    $t=$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
    echo $t;
    if ($t=='http'){return 'http';}
    else {return 'https';}
}
if (ishttp()=='http'){
    setcookie('val','http',time()+90000);
}
else{
    setcookie('val','https',time()+90000);
}
```

I tested on two hosts
There was no problem with a host

[image Https output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02AFc.jpg)
[image Http output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBxCO.jpg)

Comment: I appreciate that this doesn't really answer your question, but have you thought about forcing your users over to https? You can set it up in your htaccess to automatically push users from http to https. 99% of users won't even notice it _and_ your website is more secure.

Comment: delete the stored cookie and then run the site again with http: - it will be there.

Comment: @dearsina Some devices, such as Android 4 browser, cannot open my site https

Comment: @dean If I open https again
The http cookie is cleared

Comment: change the name of the cookie at `http:` and `https:` so that your cookies are saved differently. your cookie have the same  name

Comment: Have you looked in your browser at the cookie, to make sure that for some reason the 'secure' flag isn't being set for it? Just to rule that out.

Comment: Side note: If a browser doesn't support HTTPS... then its not a browser you should ever consider supporting as well. HTTPS is the now and future.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it once with domain parameter  with "/" for same domain:

```
 header('Cache-Control: no-store');
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    function ishttp(){
        $t=$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
        echo $t;
        if ($t=='http'){return 'http';}
        else {return 'https';}
    }
    if (ishttp()=='http'){
        setcookie('val','http',time()+90000,"/");
    }
    else{
        setcookie('val','https',time()+90000,"/");
    }
```